# Guardar Arraylist en un Array

Tags: java

Tenemos un arraylist para Empleado, y otro para Cliente, dentro tenemos los objetos de Persona.

Queremos crear un array de Personas, en el cual puede ser Empleado o Cliente, 
después queremos guardar ese Arraylist en Array.

Estoy intentando que el Array Personas guarde los dos tipos de persona, Empleado y cliente. Pero no me deja la zona comentada.

> type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to String

```
ArrayList<Persona> Empleados = new ArrayList<Persona>();
ArrayList<Persona> Clientes = new ArrayList<Persona>();
Persona Emp1 = new Persona("David", "5376461F", true);
Persona Emp2 = new Persona("Adrian", "546545C", true);
Empleados.add(Emp1);
Empleados.add(Emp2);
Persona Cl1 = new Persona("Antonio", "20216847D", false);
Persona Cl2 = new Persona("Monica", "85798521L", false);
Clientes.add(Cl1);
Clientes.add(Cl2);

for (Object o : Empleados) {
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}

for (Object o : Clientes) {
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}

//TODO
//Persona ArrayPersonas[]= new Persona[Empleados.size()+Clientes.size()];
//ArrayPersonas[0]=Clientes.toArray();
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer en sí? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Comment: he editado la publicación poniendo lo que estoy intentando

Comment: Esto no lo entiendo: *Queremos crear un array de Personas, en el cual puede ser Empleado o Cliente. Y después queremos guardar ese Arraylist en Array*. Parece que es un ejercicio, si lo es te digo que está mal, porque se requiere un array de objetos del tipo `Empleado` y otro de objetos del tipo `Cliente`. No estás instanciando objetos de ese tipo en tu código y vas a suspender nada más por eso.

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia `Clientes.toArray()` ya crea un array, no necesitas inicializar uno antes. Si quieres unir los dos ArrayList en un único array puedes hacer esto:

```
//creamos un nuevo ArrayList, con todos los empleados
ArrayList<Persona> aux = new ArrayList(Empleados); 
//añadimos los clientes
aux.addAll(Clientes);
//creamos un array
Persona [] array= aux.toArray();
```

Por cierto, te recomendaría usar las convenciones de Java al nombrar variables: deberían empezar con minúscula, para diferenciarlas de las clases.